# Deserialize possible children, which might have properties that needs to be deserialized

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, signalr

On my ASP.NET backend, I return an array of models, called `Job`, that can have `n` amount of jobs as children, using SignalR. One job could look like this:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "json": '{"error": "Some error"}',
  "children": [{
    "id": 1
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "children": [{
      "id": 4,
      "json": '{"error": "Some other error"}'
    }]
  }]
}
```

As you can see, each job can have a child, which can have another child, and so on. Each job also has a `json` property, which is JSON in a text string. I want to deserialize these to a regular JavaScript object, which looks like this:

```
var deserialized = {
  "id": 0,
  "json": {
      "error": "Some error"
  },
  "children": [{
    "id": 1
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "children": [{
      "id": 4,
      "json": {
          "error": "Some other error"
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

So basically goes like this:

1. If the job has a `json` property simply do `job.json = JSON.parse(job.json)`
2. If the job has children, loop over all the children
3. Repeat 1

How can I achieve this? I guess recursion is a way, but I'd rather see if it's possible to utilize the new ES6 methods.

Comment: I added answer. I hope it will work as per your expectation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.If the job has a json property simply do job.json = JSON.parse(job.json)
>
> 2.If the job has children, loop over all the children
>
> 3.Repeat 1

Suppose, in a job you have both properties json with `JSON string` and also `children` then we have to execute both the points (1 & 2) one by one to convert the nested `json` property of the job into `JSON Object`.

In that case, first we have to convert the `json` property into `JSON Object` and then again we have to iterate the whole job with children array.

Try Array [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) method with [ES6 Arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function.

**Working Demo :**

```js
let jobs = [{
  "id": 0,
  "json": '{"error": "Some error"}',
  "children": [{
    "id": 1
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "children": [{
      "id": 4,
      "json": '{"error": "Some other error"}'
    }]
  }]
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "json": '{"error": "Some error"}',
  "children": [{
    "id": 2
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "children": [{
      "id": 5,
      "json": '{"error": "Some other error"}'
    }]
  }]
}];

function parseObj(job) {
 let res;
 if (typeof job !== 'object') {
   return;
 } else {
  res = job.filter(elem => (elem.json && typeof elem.json == 'string')?elem.json = JSON.parse(elem.json):parseObj(elem.children))
    .filter(elem => (elem.json && typeof elem.json == 'string')?elem.json = JSON.parse(elem.json):parseObj(elem.children));
 }
 return res;
}


console.log(parseObj(jobs));
```

Comment: Works pretty well! Added a few extra children, which has multiple children and those have children as well (kind of edge-casing here), and that works as well! Thanks :)